Determine all integers $m\ge2$ for which there exists an integer $n\ge1$ with $\gcd(m,n)=d$ and $\gcd(m,4n+1)=1$
Let $m = dk$ and $n = dl$, $k,l \in Z⁺$.
Then, we can reformulate the problem as: Determine all integers $m=dk\ge2$ for which there exists an integer $n=dl\ge1$ with $\gcd(k,l)=1$ and $\gcd(k,4dl+1)=1$.
The answer is clearly $m\equiv0\pmod d$, though I don't know how to solve it.
Source: Mathematical Mediterranean Competition, 2020 Problem 1

Well, pick a multiple of $d$ and try to construct a suitable $n$.  A few examples should help.  In general, starting with examples is always a good idea.

Please edit to include your efforts.  Suppose $d=1$...can you do it then?  What if $d=2$?  I note that you didn't quantify $d$ in any way....I guess you mean "for any given $d\in \mathbb N$" but that should be clarified.

Wouldn't it be all integers?  Let $m\ge 2$.  Them $m\ge 1$ and $\gcd(m,m) =m$.   And $\gcd(m, 4m+1) =1$.  So that's every integer isn't it? Or is $d$ a specific integer.  I assumed it was not because it was never introduced except as the gcd of whatever we choose for $m$ and for $n$.
